# Two CW complexes with the same number of $n$-cells for each $n$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

i am trying to understand Theorem 5.20 in Lee's Introduction to Topological manifolds

[image: Theorem]

I am interested in the uniqueness part. Does this mean that two CW complexes with the same number of $n$-cells for each $n \geq 0$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: Certainly not. With four $0$-cells and three $1$-cells, you can construct a tree or a line graph. These are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing here is the data of the attaching maps. Both $S^1\vee S^2$ and $\Bbb RP^2$ have cell structures with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell, and one $2$-cell. If we attach the $2$-cell with the trivial map, we get $S^1\vee S^2$. If we attach with the antipodal map $S^1\to S^1$, we get $\Bbb RP^2$.

Comment: So what the theorem says is that "attaching the cells in a certain way we can obtain just one CW complex", right?

Comment: That's right, and some care is probably needed to interpret exactly how $X$ has "a unique cell decomposition making it into a CW complex whose $n$-skeleton is $X_n$ for each $n$." The point is that a CW complex is nothing more than the data of the number of cells in each dimension and their attaching maps.

Comment: But say you have two $0$-cells labeled $x_0$ and $x_1$. You could attach the $1$-cell $[0,1]$ by gluing $0\to x_0$ and $1\to x_1$, OR you could glue $0\to x_1$ and $1\to x_0$. Either way the resulting space is the same (just an interval), but the attaching maps were different.